# vim - how to use complete_check() on mapping

Tags: vim, mapping, ultisnips, supertab

while Integrating ultisnip and supertab - I am trying to map F7 so if there are completion to be made with supertab or ultisnip - try to complete, otherwise if there are no suggested patterns (and ultisnip cant expand), ultisnip forwardsJump.

but complete_check() always return 0

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<C-l>"
imap <expr> <F7> complete_check() == 0 ? "<\tab>" : "\<C-l>"
```

can somebody help me make it work?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From `:help complete_check()`:

```
Check for a key typed while looking for completion matches.
This is to be used when looking for matches takes some time.
Returns |TRUE| when searching for matches is to be aborted,
zero otherwise.
Only to be used by the function specified with the
'completefunc' option.
```

Are you sure `complete_check()` is the right tool for the job?

Comment: I couldn't find anything else.. I am looking for whatever function or var that can tell me if there are any completions to be made. The only one I found for now is pumvisible() but that is for after trying to complete already..

Comment: Completion is done dynamically so you can only know if completion is possible *after* asking for completion. See `:help completion_info()`, which can be used as part of a quick `:help complete()` function or a more involved `:help complete-functions`. For your use case, `:help pumvisible()` seems to be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this world of code and vim. I will try reading and using :help pumvisible() as you suggested